# Dealing with a problem that contains a specific structure with a standard MILP solver

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, solver

Suppose we have a specific formulation in which contains a special structure. For example, the formulation has a block diagonal format with some linking constraints. As far as I know, this format would be suitable for the decomposition scheme. Now, I am interested to know, is there any benefit to using this special structure with the standard MILP solvers?

Comment: Did you mean to solve this special structure problem without using any decomposition method?

Comment: @ytsao, yes. Exactly. I want to know if this kind of formulation may help standard mip solvers or not.

Comment: in my opinion, if you work in company then maybe use standard MILP solvers would be easier maintain. Because not everyone can understand the knowledge about decomposition algorithms. But, trade-off would be increasing the runtime to solve.

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, may I have your insight regarding this?